# Laravel Excel 3.1 throws a "property doesnt have a default value" error despite importing successfully

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-excel

I am using the Laravel Excel package to handle bulk uploads. Whilst Im able to get the data to upload successfully, my web console indicates and error that 'staff_id' doesn't have a default value. I have tried to catch this as an exception but this does not get triggered. I am using the ToModel import as indicated below

```
class EmployeesImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        try {
            return new Employee([
                'staff_id' => $row['staff_id'],
                'first_name' => $row['first_name'],
                'middle_name' => $row['middle_name'],
                'last_name' => $row['last_name'],
                'national_id' => (string) $row['national_id'],
                'department_id' => 1,
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage(), $row);
        }
    }
}
```

The CSV Im importing has the following structure

[image: Excel that Im importing with input name ('bulk')]

Within my controller, I have this to exceute the upload/import

```
Excel::import(new EmployeesImport(), request()->file('bulk'));
```

And finally, this is my Employees Model, showing the fillable fields

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "employees";

    protected $fillable = [
        "staff_id", "first_name", "middle_name", "last_name", "national_id", "department_id", "avatar"
    ];
}
```

(One last thing) In case it may hold relevance - my migration file's up method

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('staff_id')->unique();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('middle_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('national_id')->unique();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id');
        $table->longText('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        //Foreign keys
        $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: on the documentation I saw Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx'); and in your code I see you are using as new UsersImport() as function, is there any difference in using one or the other

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, both syntax should work the same way in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you can catch the errors at the end

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#gathering-all-failures-at-the-end

> Gathering all failures at the end
>
> You can gather all validation
>   failures at the end of the import, when used in conjunction with Batch
>   Inserts. You can try-catch the ValidationException. On this exception
>   you can get all failures.
>
> Each failure is an instance of Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure.
>   The Failure holds information about which row, which column and what
>   the validation errors are for that cell.

```
try {
    // import code
} catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
     $failures = $e->failures();

     foreach ($failures as $failure) {
         $failure->row(); // row that went wrong
         $failure->attribute(); // either heading key (if using heading row concern) or column index
         $failure->errors(); // Actual error messages from Laravel validator
         $failure->values(); // The values of the row that has failed.
     }
}
```

Comment: The import definition of ToModel Ive defined above doesnt throw that Exception.

Answer (score 0):

you make your models like that:

```
protected $fillable = [
        "staff_id", "first_name", "middle_name", "last_name", "national_id", "department_id", "avatar"
    ];
```

and your row like this:

```
return new Employee([
                'staff_id' => $row['staff_id'],
                'first_name' => $row['first_name'],
                'middle_name' => $row['middle_name'],
                'last_name' => $row['last_name'],
                'national_id' => (string) $row['national_id'],
                'department_id' => 1,
```

just matching the $row and $fillable, i mean in your $row the "avatar" must have a value to fill the $fillable, 
or you can erase the "avatar" from you fillable